What is the correct way to secure joists if you only have access to the inside corner?
I have a 10'x20' area that has 8' tall 2x4" 16" oc double top plate framing around the entire perimeter. I am looking to frame out a floor above it with 2x10" joists "|" & rim joists "-". I only have access from the inside of this area as each side has taller walls. In each corner where a joist meets the rim joist (x) is a Simpson Strong-Tie Framing Angle strong enough to single handledly secure the two together? If not, how should I go about this?
x <--- RIM JOIST ---> x
| | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | |
x <--- RIM JOIST ---> x


Rim joists aren't conventionally connected with framing hardware. They're face-nailed together from the outside, and then the floor sheathing essentially locks them in place.
Since you're not able to face-nail them together, use anything that approximates that connection, such as your angle bracket. Again, this isn't hypercritical. You mostly want them held together until the sheathing is on. You could also use angle brackets along the joist/sill plate interface to accomplish the same thing.
One other idea would be to secure blocks (vertical rails) to one joist before setting it in position so you can simply nail or screw those to the other joist.
_____________________________
                             |
_____________________________|
                   |    |    |
                   |____|    | <-- FASTEN FIRST
                        |    |
  FASTEN SECOND -----^  |    |

